# How to get the .resx file strings in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How to get the resx file strings in asp.net core?
I get the strings using ResxResourceReader in mvc. But I can't get the same in asp.net core.

Comment: I want to access the entries in resx file as keyvalue pair. How to do this in dotnet core

Answer (score 60, accepted):

.NET Core changed how resource files work in a way I feel is sub-par and confusing (took me days to figure out), but this is what you need to do:

1. Add the following code to Startup.cs - Note: Change what languages you support and the ResourcePath of "Resources" will just be the folder you store the .resx files later.

> As [JustAMartin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217823/justamartin) said in comments: If you are planning to put your **SharedResource** file inside **Resources** folder and set its namespace to end with Resources then do not set **`o.ResourcesPath = "Resources"`** just use **`services.AddLocalization()`**, otherwise it will start looking in Resources.Resources folder, which doesn't exist.

```
        services.AddLocalization(o => o.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
                new CultureInfo("de-DE")
            };
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US", "en-US");

            // You must explicitly state which cultures your application supports.
            // These are the cultures the app supports for formatting 
            // numbers, dates, etc.

            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;

            // These are the cultures the app supports for UI strings, 
            // i.e. we have localized resources for.

            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });
```

2. Create a folder in whatever project you want to store the resx files in - default, call it "Resources".
3. Create a new resx file with the specific culture and the file name you'll look up later:  If you had a shared one, you could do:  SharedResource.en-US.resx.  Then turn off auto-code generation as it is useless now.
4. Create a class called "SharedResource" in the same location as your resx file.  It can be blank, it just needs to be there so you can reference it later.
5. Wherever you want to use your resource, IoC inject (in this example) IStringLocalizer< SharedResource > with name "_localizer" or something.
6. Finally, you can reference an entry in the Resource file by doing _localizer["My_Resource_Name"]
7. Add another language by creating a new resx file named "SharedResource.de-DE.resx" or whatever, in that same folder.

The "Resource" folder will be used across all assemblies to look all of them up.  Thus, this folder could end up pretty cluttered, especially if you start getting view specific stuff in here.

I see what the devs were trying to do here, but they gave up too much to get there.  People can code and add translation stuff without actually translating anything.  They made it easier for devs to have translation in mind from the start, but they end up making it way more work for the devs that actually use translations.  Now we can't auto generate anything.  We have to IoC inject a reference to the translations in order to access them (no more static unless you want to use the ServiceLocater anti-pattern).  All the names are hard-coded strings, so now if you spell a translation wrong it'll just spit back the string you gave it, defeating the purpose of having a translation in the first place, meaning you'll probably need a wrapper around this so you don't rely on constants everywhere.

I can't believe anyone thought this was a good idea, to be honest.  Why bend over backwards for devs that don't care about translations, anyway?

I ended up creating a wrapper around this style.  The only good thing about this is that if you decide you want to get resources from the database, no code change above will be necessary, but now you have to add the resource entry, add it to the interface, and then implement it to pull it back out again. I used nameof() so I didn't need to use constants, but this is still brittle as if the property name or resx file name changes, it'll break the translation without any sort of crash - I will probably need an integration test to ensure I don't get the same value I send in:

```
public interface ICommonResource
{
    string ErrorUnexpectedNumberOfRowsSaved { get; }
    string ErrorNoRecordsSaved { get; }
    string ErrorConcurrency { get; }
    string ErrorGeneric { get; }

    string RuleAlreadyInUse { get; }
    string RuleDoesNotExist { get; }
    string RuleInvalid { get; }
    string RuleMaxLength { get; }
    string RuleRequired { get; }
}

public class CommonResource : ICommonResource
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<CommonResource> _localizer;

    public CommonResource(IStringLocalizer<CommonResource> localizer) =>
        _localizer = localizer;

    public string ErrorUnexpectedNumberOfRowsSaved => GetString(nameof(ErrorUnexpectedNumberOfRowsSaved));
    public string ErrorNoRecordsSaved => GetString(nameof(ErrorNoRecordsSaved));
    public string ErrorConcurrency => GetString(nameof(ErrorConcurrency));
    public string ErrorGeneric => GetString(nameof(ErrorGeneric));

    public string RuleAlreadyInUse => GetString(nameof(RuleAlreadyInUse));
    public string RuleDoesNotExist => GetString(nameof(RuleDoesNotExist));
    public string RuleInvalid => GetString(nameof(RuleInvalid));
    public string RuleMaxLength => GetString(nameof(RuleMaxLength));
    public string RuleRequired => GetString(nameof(RuleRequired));

    private string GetString(string name) =>
        _localizer[name];
}
```

Comment: I believe that you can still use the `ResXFileCodeGenerator` to generate compile-time props (as seen here for example: https://christianspecht.de/2017/11/29/fixing-resourcedesignercs-generation-in-net-core/ ).

Comment: I did but then the culture change was ignored for me.

Comment: In an old project using ASP.Net 5, I have a separated project containing one global file with all the translated string (e.g.: Translations.resx and Translations.fr.resx, Translations.nl.resx, etc). Is this still possible with ASP.Net Core 2? Even if I can't use a second project for the files. Because I can't find how to do this.

Comment: I found a workaround. I'm using a "BaseController" and two resx files: "Controllers.BaseController.resx" and "Controllers.BaseController.fr.resx". This class in inherited by my "true" controllers and I pass a "Text" var which contains the "IStringLocalizer" object with the translated string to the models (again, I use a "BaseModel" for this). This is quite ugly, but this is as close as I wanted. I also use a Constant class to not deal with the string keys, I hate that and we can always mistype something. I may write a blog post one day to explain this in a proper way.

Comment: @Mayako It looks like you need to call this instead in ASP.NET Core 2: `services.AddLocalization();` - I know it's probably too late for you but it might help others :)

Comment: It can even help me since I'm still with my "ugly" workaround! Thanks :)

Comment: Beware of two "gotchas": 1) IStringLocalizer doesn't like short culture names. It just didn't work with `lv` although current thread cultures and resource name was `lv`. It started to work when I renamed them all to `lv-LV`. 2) if you put your SharedResource file inside Resources folder and set its namespace to end with `Resources` then do not set `o.ResourcesPath = "Resources"` because then it will start looking in `Resources.Resources` folder, which doesn't exist. So, it's either namespace or ResourcesPath but not both.

Comment: Given this solution what is the YAML syntax for accessing the resources?

Comment: @DanielLorenz It doesn't work for me: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.IStringLocalizer, Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor

Comment: @LucaZiegler It sounds like you are trying to inject in a Razor view.  The above code is for controller injection.  If you want Razor, you would do something like this:  \@inject IHtmlLocalizer<SharedResource> SharedLocalizer

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it really helped. The documentation is really messy and don't know why doesn't include a code snippet as accurate as yours ‍♂️. I used to also use that wrapper pattern with the `nameof` trick for UWP apps too, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

The old way version (like in asp.net) is to create a default resource file like MyResources.resx and other files for different cultures MyResources.fr.resx, ... and retrieve the values from it with MyResources.MyValue1 . Creating MyResources.resx will generate a .cs file with all your resource values as static properties.

.Net Core recommends to work with `IStringLocalizer<T>` where T is a class created by you that match with the name of your resource files. You can start development without any resource file and add them later. You have to inject **(IStringLocalizer< MyResources > localizer)** on your controller and than get the value with _localizer["MyValue1"];

You can take a look over the .net core official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization)

Comment: Why would they do that?  Now we have to use strings that will let you get run-time crashes...

Comment: @DanielLorenz: If X is undefined, usually `localizer[X] == X` .  So you usually won't get run-time crashes.  If your internal policy is that `localizer[X] == X` should be true for your default culture, this gives pretty good results.  A further benefit of this approach is that it forces you to be explicit about whether you want a string localizer or an html localizer.  That said, the real reason MVC took this approach is because MVC uses dependency injection for everything.

Comment: Beyond string vs. html, the only real-world case I can think of for wanting to use dependency injection for your localizer is to inject a custom, "I forgot to localize" string during debugging.  If you replace your unlocalized strings with similar strings (e.g., add an accent mark over most of your characters), spotting raw strings becomes easier.

Comment: @Brian This message was before I knew how it was working.  I expected it to crash if you used a string value that didn't exist in the Resource File.  Now I found out that if it doesn't exist, it will just spit back out the value you gave it.  This seems pointless because translators will give a good naming key while non-translators are going to put the actual text in there with no context just so they MIGHT be able to translate it later.  Now you have to use nameof() or constants everywhere or someone could rename stuff and you'd end up not even using a translation now. This feels bad.

Comment: @DanielLorenz: I agree with you; I prefer the designer approach (which still works in .Net Core).  The cost you pay for statically defining every resource string is that your resource class is tightly coupled with your application.  That cost is incompatible with Microsoft's attempt to avoid all dependencies in favor of modular, injectable components.  In the case of third-party libraries, avoiding coupling has substantial merit.  In the case of application-specific localization, your translation is inherently coupled to your application, so tight coupling has minimal downsides.

Comment: @Brian Sure, I get the IoC thing, but the Resx class could have just implemented this interface and the generated code could have took care of all of this instead of relying on a random string that ends up spitting out the same value it got if it doesn't find an entry.

Comment: @DanielLorenz: No, that doesn't work.  Fundamentally, any approach that provides you with intellisense/type-safety on generated properties cannot be used for proper dependency injection.  If you inject a generic interface, you lose intellisense/type-safety (which is the specific reason you and I dislike the Microsoft's approach).  If you inject an implementation (syntactically legal), you may as well not use dependency injection at all, since you've just tied yourself to a specific implementation.

Comment: @Brian Microsoft could have changed the resx designer to generate not only the class with all the items in it but also an interface that implements all the properties in the resx file along with the localizer portion.  If they auto generated that, we could simply IoC inject IMyResources class that the resx generated and then you can use the properties directly there. If someone changed something, it wouldn't compile anymore as that method would be gone from the interface.  That's all I meant. :)

Comment: @DanielLorenz: I understood what you meant.  I'm saying that your suggestion is a misuse of DI.

Comment: @Brian How so? IMyResource would be injected anyway with all properties to get full safety instead of single method with crappy string with no safety at all. Having constants everywhere would be bad vs having the method.

Comment: I didn't say your approach doesn't have type safety, I said it ruins DI.  If `IMyResource` has identical properties to `MyResource`, your code is tightly coupled to `MyResource`.  You may as well just use `MyResource` directly, rather than using DI.  Your interface is so similar to your implementation that the only way you can inject an alternatve implementation is with a binary compatibile implementation...which you can already do without DI.

Comment: The issue I have with the Microsoft implementation is that it's worse for people who need internationalization and isn't useful for people who don't need internationalization.  Making even a slight correction to a string will lose you your translations.  Much better to have the tightly coupled Resources files.

Comment: The old resx files can be used anywhere without dependencies (You can use them inside any kind of project or components library without dependencies). The IStringLocalizer approach works only in the context of an application which is quite problematic I think.

Answer (score 5):

For a more direct replacement, I have created [ResXResourceReader.NetStandard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ResXResourceReader.NetStandard), which repackages `ResXResourceReader` and `ResXResourceWriter` for .NET Standard (which means .NET Core too).