# How to get value of specific key from resource file in ASPNET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I wanna get value of a key in resource (.resx) file in .net core API. I followed the marked answer and implemented in my code. But When I am fetching value by key then only Key name is coming.

The linked is below which I followed :

[How to get the .resx file strings in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43181904/how-to-get-the-resx-file-strings-in-asp-net-core/48133924)

Please help me for this.

Thanks

Comment: did you try this ? https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/programmatically-retrieving-items-from-resource-files-in-.net

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI , I checked it also but I am working in .Net Core and I need to call any single Key to get the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example , you could refer to :

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=WebAPIDbContext;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";
        services.AddDbContext<RestaurantContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

        services.AddLocalization(o => o.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

        services.AddMvc()   
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        //Request Localization
        //var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
        //app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);

        var supportedCultures = new[]
       {
            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
            new CultureInfo("zh-cn"),
        };

        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
            // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            // UI strings that we have localized.
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
        });

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Controller

```
private readonly IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> _sharedLocalizer;
    public ValuesController(IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> sharedLocalizer)
    {
        _sharedLocalizer = sharedLocalizer;
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
    {
        var value = _sharedLocalizer["Title"];
        return "value";
    }
```

Resource file path

[image]

Note : the namespace of SharedResource.cs should be the root of application

```
namespace RestaurantReviewApi
{ 
  public class SharedResource
  {
  }
}
```

Request url : `https://localhost:44318/api/values/3?culture=zh-cn`

The screenshot of result :
[image]

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Thanks for giving answer but You didn't check the attached link Which I added with question. The same thing is being done by me. But the statement is only returning the key :  

string title=_sharedLocalizer["Title"];   

Then the title is having only "Title". It means the key Which is given by me not the "title" key' value.

Comment: @Deepak ,  I reproduced the problem successfully and solved it  . Please pay attention to these two points. First, the [culture name](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e1BX7M) in `CultureInfo()` must be specifically supported.  Second, when you want to get the value of the specific key in a language , you need to set the corresponding language in the request, the simplest is to use the query string (check my edited), the other two ways for `CookieRequestCultureProvider` and `AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider`, you could refer to the link provided in my reply for more details.